# How to detect the dominant language of a text word?

Tags: ios, swift, nlp, nslinguistictagger

It's looks good for `string` but it's not working for me for a `word`. I am working with search as per as my requirement when user typing any 3 character in the meantime looking to check which language user typing. if I think it should not work with `detec0t` word but i expect it should be working with `Islam` word.

```
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes:[.tokenType, .language, .lexicalClass, .nameType, .lemma], options: 0)

func determineLanguage(for text: String) {
    tagger.string = text
    let language = tagger.dominantLanguage
    print("The language is \(language!)")
}


//Test case
determineLanguage(for: "I love Islam") // en -pass
determineLanguage(for: "আমি ইসলাম ভালোবাসি") // bn -pass
determineLanguage(for: "أنا أحب الإسلام") // ar -pass
determineLanguage(for: "Islam") // und - failed
```

**Result:**

> The language is en 
>   The language is bn 
>   The language is ar 
>   The language is und

What I missed for "Unknown language"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because it belongs to too many languages and it would be unrealistic to guess the language based on one word. The context always helps.

For example :

```
import NaturalLanguage

let recognizer = NLLanguageRecognizer()
recognizer.processString("Islam")
print(recognizer.dominantLanguage!.rawValue)  //Force unwrapping for brevity
```

prints `tr`, which stands for Turkish. It's an educated guess.

If you want the other languages that were also possible, you could use [`languageHypotheses(withMaximum:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nllanguagerecognizer/3017456-languagehypotheses):

```
let hypotheses = recognizer.languageHypotheses(withMaximum: 10)

for (lang, confidence) in hypotheses.sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value }) {
    print(lang.rawValue, confidence)
}
```

Which prints

> ```
> tr 0.2332388460636139   //Turkish
> hr 0.1371040642261505   //Croatian
> en 0.12280254065990448  //English
> pt 0.08051242679357529
> de 0.06824589520692825
> nl 0.05405258387327194
> nb 0.050924140959978104
> it 0.037797268480062485
> pl 0.03097432479262352
> hu 0.0288708433508873
> ```

Now you could define an acceptable threshold of confidence in order to accept that result.

---

<sup>Language codes can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp)</sup>

Comment: Would you tell me please? Can I set the country code before Which may be in the middle of the language. for example `Islam` word into 3 language **English, Arabic, Bangla**

Comment: @NazmulHasan you could compare the confidence associated with those languages in the `hypotheses`. In the example above, English would be the highest, Arabic and Bangla would be `nil`. If it’s still not clear enough, you could ask a new question and feel free to tag me. Ramadan kareem!

Comment: Ramadan Kareem!